# Aframe Checkpoints and camera view

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm using aframe for a VR project I'm doing and I'm using checkpoint on the ground to lead the user around the 3D space. I received help before on how to create a checkpoint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60856290/how-do-i-use-checkpoint-controls-in-a-frame?noredirect=1#comment107769224_60856290)

Here is the link to the most current iteration of my project -> https://museum-exhibit-demo.glitch.me/webVR.html

Is it possible to have the animation that takes you to the cylinder also change the view of the camera and height? Basically once I click the cylinder to take me to the position it will also snap my view to the text on the wall even if it is not eye height

Answer (score 0):

Great Demo. I've prepared a candidate solution on [glitch](https://glitch.com/~museum-exhibit-demo-mod) ([app](https://museum-exhibit-demo-mod.glitch.me/webVR.html)). This solution changes the height of the camera, and the horizontal direction/yaw of the camera. It does not change the pitch of the camera. Ideally any AR/VR app would minimise forcing a change of camera orientation. If you forcibly change the pitch of the camera that's like permanently tilting the floor of the user. If you just change the yaw then that just permanently changes the horizontal direction they are look. Changing the pitch can be done, but I think from a user perspective that might cause more problems than it is worth, changing the yaw is just about OK. Similar recommendations were previously mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47667912/10849562.

I'll break down the solution code by how it solves your two issues, to have the animation that takes you to the cylinder also change the height of the camera, and separately how it can change the view/direction? I'll add in line references to the solution were relevant.

- **Change the height to match the height of the text**
  First you need to know the height of the text associated with the checkpoint cylinder. One way to do this is to provide the `id` of the related `a-text` entity to the `goto` component. To do that I added a new component property `textId` to your `goto` component ([`L79`](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/museum-exhibit-demo-mod?path=webVR.html:79:0)). Then in each of the places where you have used the `goto` component the `textId` property was set. For example for the checkpoint cylinder associated with the `Welcome!` text, the `goto` component was changed to `goto="textId: welcome"` ([`L298`](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/museum-exhibit-demo-mod?path=webVR.html:298:7)).

  The `id` of the associated `a-text` enitity can be accessed from methods of the `goto` component using `this.data.textId` which will be different for each `goto` component. Using this information within the component, the position of the `a-text` enitity can be found in a similar way to how you found the `rig` position, by finding the `a-text` element with `document.querySelector` [`L83`](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/museum-exhibit-demo-mod?path=webVR.html:83:68) and then finding the position [`L93`](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/museum-exhibit-demo-mod?path=webVR.html:97:28).

  ```js
  let text = document.querySelector(`#${this.data.textId}`);
  text.object3D.getWorldPosition(textPos);
  ```

  Note that instead of using `text.getAttribute("position")` the `getWorldPosition` method is used instead. That is because you have wrapped your `a-text` elements inside `a-entity` elements that also have positions set. `getAttribute("position")` only gives you the position relative to its parent entity, but this solution requires the absolute/world position of the text. Of course other solutions might do things different, and it's also possible to change the HTML structure of your demo so that you could use `getAttribute("position")`. [`getWorldPosition`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldPosition) is a method from THREE.js (which A-Frame is based on) and stores the position in the `textPos` variable. You can use `textPos` in the same way as `rigPos`. Instead of `rigPos.y` you can now do `textPos.y` to get the height of the text as the end point of the position animation to change the height of the camera.

  Note that 1.6 is taken away from the height in the solution. The default height of the camera in A-Frame is 1.6. You've handled this by reducing the position of the camera by -1.1 in the `#pov` entity.
- **Change the direction of the camera match the direction of the text**

  First we need to know the direction of the text with respect to its associated checkpoint cylinder. Because we now have access to the position of the cylinder the direction vector between from the cylinder to the text can be calculated (`L111`). From this the azimuthal angle or yaw angle of the direction from the checkpoint cylinder to the text can be calculated (`L115`). To do this calculation a function `getYaw` was created (`L46`) to calculate the yaw angle.

  Because you have already applied a yaw rotation of 90 degrees on your `#pov` entity that wraps your `a-camera` entity, the yaw angle is calculated from the negative z-axis `(0, 0, -1)`.

  Now that you have the direction the text is from the checkpoint cylinder, you need to know the yaw direction the camera is currently pointing in. You can find this out from the  `rotation` component of the `a-camera` entity. Just like finding the position of any entity, you can find the `a-camera` element with `document.querySelector` (`L84`) and the find its yaw angle `camera.getAttribute("rotation").y` (`L116`). You can then calculate the target yaw angle that you should set the `rig` to by calculating the relative angle from the `camera` entity to the `text` entity which is called `targetRigYaw` in the solution (L117).

  Note that there are lots of applications of a `mod` function. This simply ensures that all yaw angles are always positive and between [0, 360] which helps simplify things when applying angles.

  You could now use the `targetRigYaw` as the angle to set your rig to to change the view direction to look at the text. However depending on the yaw angles of the text direction and camera direction, this angle might be greater than 180 degrees. You can imagine that you could rotate left or right to end up looking in a particular direction. Unless the direction you would like to look in is directly behind you, one of the direction will be a shorted rotation than the other. `L120-123` change the `targetRigYaw` angle so that you are always rotating in the shortest angular direction to end up looking at the text.

  In order to animate the yaw in the same way as you animated the position you can add second component to the `#pov` entity. In the solution this is called `animation__rotation` (`L144`). The A-Frame docs describe how you can add multiple animation using the `__` notation https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/animation.html#multiple-animations.

  We can then set the `animation__rotation` component to perform an animation of the `rotation` of the `#pov` entity in a similar way to the `position`. The `animation__rotation` component is set using `setAttribute` to rotate from the current yaw angle of the `rig` to the `targetRigYaw` angle, and the duration of the animation is set to the same length as the position animation.

I hope this helps solve your two questions. Please let me know if you have any questions. I've added comment to the code, however there were quite a few snippets that I added that might not be obvious what they do.